# PHPStorm 10, XAMPP, Zend Debugger

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, zend-studio

I am using Mac OS X Yosemite v10.10.2 I would like to use Zend Debugger with PHPStorm 10. I have downloaded the ZendDebugger.so from their site and moved it to a local folder in my XAMPP directory (same location as php.ini // /Applications/XAMPP/xampfiles/etc/ZendDebugger.so).

In PHPStorm I have the correct Interpreter setup for PHP5.5 but it says "Debugger: Not Installed". I have modified my php.ini with the following code but to no avail.

```
[Zend Debugger]
zend_extension=/Applications/XAMPP/xampfiles/etc/ZendDebugger.so
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=localhost
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=allowed_host
zend_debugger.tunnel_min_port=1024
zend_debugger.tunnel_max_port=65000
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for fixing this?

Sam

Comment: Why don't you try using xdebug instead? xdebug works flawlessly on phpstorm 10.

Comment: @LauriOrgla I could only see Windows download files and as far as I know .dll files don't work on Mac OS.

Comment: You can get xdebug as .so file also. https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-xdebug.html , You might have to compile it tho.

Comment: OSX comes with xdebug already installed, along with php, mysql, apache, but I'd think it could be configured for xampp if versions match?